# how to get anchor links to work on bootstrap accordion and tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've succesfully set up angular-ui bootstrap [Tabs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) & [Accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/accordion) to use one or the other dependent on the width of the screen.

I would like it so that when the user goes to the page with an anchor link in the URL it will open the appropriate tab/accordion, e.g. example.com/page#statistics

Maybe I need to use `$routeParams` `$location` in the AngularJS Controller I'm using to get the anchor link and set the which tab/accordion to open?

Here is the Markup I'm using with the angular-ui bootstrap directives:

```
<div window-size class="col-xs-12">
    <uib-tabset active="active" ng-if="windowWidth >= 768">
        <uib-tab index="0" heading="overview">
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/overview.html'"></div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="1" heading="statistics">
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/statistics.html'"></div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab index="2" heading="live updates">
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/live-updates.html'"></div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
    <uib-accordion close-others="true" ng-if="windowWidth < 768">
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="overview" is-open="true">
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/overview.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="statistics">
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/statistics.html'"></div>
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="updates">
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/live-updates.html'"></div>
        </div>
    </uib-accordion>
</div>
```

And here is the markup output to the browser for the Tabs:

```
<div active="active" ng-if="windowWidth >= 768" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" ng-class="{'nav-stacked': vertical, 'nav-justified': justified}" ng-transclude="">
        <li ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]" class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope active" index="0" heading="overview">
            <a href="" ng-click="select($event)" class="nav-link ng-binding" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">overview</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]" class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" index="1" heading="statistics">
            <a href="" ng-click="select($event)" class="nav-link ng-binding" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">statistics</a>
        </li>
        <li ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]" class="uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" index="2" heading="live updates">
            <a href="" ng-click="select($event)" class="nav-link ng-binding" uib-tab-heading-transclude="">live updates</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- ngRepeat: tab in tabset.tabs -->
        <div class="tab-pane ng-scope active" ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" ng-class="{active: tabset.active === tab.index}" uib-tab-content-transclude="tab">
            <!-- ngInclude: 'app/partials/overview.html' -->
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/overview.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">overview content</h3></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabset.tabs -->
        <div class="tab-pane ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" ng-class="{active: tabset.active === tab.index}" uib-tab-content-transclude="tab">
            <!-- ngInclude: 'app/partials/statistics.html' -->
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/statistics.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">statistics content</h3></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabset.tabs -->
        <div class="tab-pane ng-scope" ng-repeat="tab in tabset.tabs" ng-class="{active: tabset.active === tab.index}" uib-tab-content-transclude="tab">    
            <!-- ngInclude: 'app/partials/live-updates.html' -->
            <div ng-include="'app/partials/live-updates.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">updates content</h3></div>
        </div>
        <!-- end ngRepeat: tab in tabset.tabs -->
  </div>
</div>
```

And the markup for the accordion that is outputted to the browser is:

```
<uib-accordion close-others="true" ng-if="windowWidth < 768" class="ng-scope">
    <div role="tablist" class="panel-group" ng-transclude="">
        <div uib-accordion-group="" class="panel-default ng-scope ng-isolate-scope panel panel-open" heading="overview" is-open="true">
            <div role="tab" id="accordiongroup-198-2711-tab" aria-selected="true" class="panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordiongroup-198-2711-panel" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading" ng-disabled="isDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle=""><span uib-accordion-header="" ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}" class="ng-binding">overview</span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="accordiongroup-198-2711-panel" aria-labelledby="accordiongroup-198-2711-tab" aria-hidden="false" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse in" uib-collapse="!isOpen" aria-expanded="true">
                <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude="">
                    <!-- ngInclude: 'app/partials/overview.html' -->
                    <div ng-include="'app/partials/overview.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">statistics content</h3></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group="" class="panel-default ng-scope ng-isolate-scope panel" heading="statistics">
            <div role="tab" id="accordiongroup-200-2865-tab" aria-selected="false" class="panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordiongroup-200-2865-panel" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading" ng-disabled="isDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle=""><span uib-accordion-header="" ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}" class="ng-binding">statistics</span></a>
                    </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="accordiongroup-200-2865-panel" aria-labelledby="accordiongroup-200-2865-tab" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude="">
                    <!-- ngInclude: 'app/partials/statistics.html' -->
                    <div ng-include="'app/partials/statistics.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">statistics content</h3></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div uib-accordion-group="" class="panel-default ng-scope ng-isolate-scope panel" heading="live updates">   <div role="tab" id="accordiongroup-202-497-tab" aria-selected="false" class="panel-heading" ng-keypress="toggleOpen($event)">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="accordiongroup-202-497-panel" class="accordion-toggle" ng-click="toggleOpen()" uib-accordion-transclude="heading" ng-disabled="isDisabled" uib-tabindex-toggle=""><span uib-accordion-header="" ng-class="{'text-muted': isDisabled}" class="ng-binding">live updates</span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="accordiongroup-202-497-panel" aria-labelledby="accordiongroup-202-497-tab" aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" uib-collapse="!isOpen" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                    <div class="panel-body" ng-transclude="">
                    <!-- ngInclude: 'app/partials/live-updates.html' -->
                    <div ng-include="'app/partials/live-updates.html'" class="ng-scope"><h3 class="ng-scope">live updates content</h3></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</uib-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the solution I came up with the `$location` service needs to be added to your controller so that you can get the anchor link param.

In the controller you then add some logic to get the anchor link and set variables to be used in the angularJS markup/directives to set which tab/accordion is active. . .

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$location', function ($location) {
    var mainCtrl = this;
    mainCtrl.anchorLink = $location.$$url.split('#')[1];

    mainCtrl.activeAccordion = {
        isOverview: true,
        isStatistics: false,
        isUpdates: false
    };
    function setActiveAccordion(activeKey) {
        for(var key in mainCtrl.activeAccordion) {
            mainCtrl.activeAccordion[key] = false;
        }
        mainCtrl.activeAccordion[activeKey] = true;
    }
    switch(mainCtrl.anchorLink) {
        case 'statistics':
            mainCtrl.activeTab = 1;
            setActiveAccordion('isStatistics');
            break;
        case 'live-updates':
            mainCtrl.activeTab = 2;
            setActiveAccordion('isUpdates');           
            break;
        default:
            mainCtrl.activeTab = 0;
            setActiveAccordion('isOverview');
            mainCtrl.anchorLink = 'overview';
    }
}]);
```

Then in your markup for tabs you need to set the `active` attribute with:

```
<uib-tabset active="mainCtrl.activeTab">
```

And for the accordion markup you need to set the `is-open` attribute with: